# Redirected to app when going to app profile page?? (cant add app to page?)

Tags: facebook, iframe, redirect, settings

I think I'm going crazy.

I made a really simple app for a client last evening, just an iframe showing a plain webpage, no real interaction with facebooks API. However, when I try going to the apps profile page to add it to the clients page (I am admin there), I am redirected to the app itself. Like this:

I try going to hxxps://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=MY_APP_ID

I am redirected to hxxp://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME/

I think I have tried every possible combination of settings for the app, I have even tried copying exactly the same settings as an earlier app I made, which works just fine, but it simply will not work. It seems as if there is no app profile page?

This are my current settings:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Application Profile pages are going to be removed soon. 
Here is blog post from facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Comment: I knew they are being removed, but at the moment I don't believe there is any other way to add an app as a tab to a page? Anyways, I found the solution moments after posting – you have to manually create a profile page for the app, you find the button to do this on the bottom of the advanced settings for the app :)

Comment: Alright, correcting myself here. The "new app profile page" does not have a option to add as an app to a page. The new way to do this, is outlined here: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-removing-app-profile-pages-on-feb-1-2012/